# Explicit column/object name in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql

In T-SQL one can run both of these queries

```
SELECT Id FROM Nodes.Main

SELECT [Id] FROM Nodes.Main
```

How can I do something similar in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Postgres complies with the SQL standard for quoting identifiers: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS  Note that in Postgres (and standard SQL) `"Id"` and `Id` are two different identifiers.

Comment: Yeah, it is exactly what I was having hard time with. the fact that it changed the names I specified in the create table made it even more confusing.

I guess I'll have some learning curve here....

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: never quote identifiers